# automatically have script input yes at windows cmd yes/no prompt

Tags: windows, cmd, automation, registry, prompt

I am interested in being able to automatically have my `cmd` input `Yes` at the `Yes/No` prompt:

> ```
>                                        __
>                                      .d$$b
>                                    .' TO$;\
>                                   /  : TP._;
>                                  / .;  :Tb/
>                                 /   /   ;j$j
>                             _.-"       d$$$$
>                           .' ..       d$$$$;
>                          /  /P'      d$$$$P. \\
>                         /   "      .d$$$P' \\^"l
>                       .'           `T$P"""""  :
>                   ._.'      _.'                ;
>                `-.-".-'-' ._.       _.-"    .-"
>              `.-" _____  ._              .-"
>             -(.g$$$$$$$b.              .'
>               ""^T$$$P)            .(:
>                 _/  -"  /.'         /:/;
>              ._.'-'`-'  ")/         /;/;
>           `-.-"..--""   " /         /  ;
>          .-" ..--""        -'          :
>          ..--""--.-"         (\      .-(\
>            ..--""              `-\(\/;`
>              _.                      :
>     .................................................__________...
>     .... _________________________________________ ./           \\
>     .___/             /..I        /_/   _____   I_ I   _______   II
>     .__/ ____       //...I   ____/  I  I.....I II..I  /...II...\ II
>     ../_____/      //....I   II ....I  I_____I II..I   ___II___  II
>     ......./      //.....I   I____..I       ___II..I  I___II___I II
>     ....../      //......I    ___/..I   I\   \\ ...I   ...II...  II
>     ...../      //.......I   II ....I   I.\   \\ ..I   ...II...  II
>     ..../      //_______ I   I______I_  I..\   \\ .I  \___II___/ II
>     .../  ____________ /_I           /  I__.\   \\ I             II
>     __/_______________/.\___________/_____/..\___\\\____________//
>
> c:\>disablewinremotedesktop
> Delete the registry value fDenyTSConnections (Yes/No)?
> ```

I have a really long `.cmd` file containing a large lists of `DOSKEY`s I have been making to speed up my computer tasks, and I am adding a few commands I know will be useful in the future based off of this registry book I have been reading in my free time.

Here is the command format:

```
DOSKEY disablewinremotedesktop = REG DELETE "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal  Server" /v "fDenyTSConnections" 
$T
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v "fDenyTSConnections" /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

In this `.cmd` file I used `@echo off` at the beginning and end, in order to make that [ASCII art picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1UkI.jpg) I like so very much.

Please help me automate this process!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a Yes.bat file with something like the following:

```
@echo off
for /L %%X in (1,1,77) do echo Yes
```

(Replace 77 with some sufficiently large number)

Then just run

```
Yes.bat | YourCommand.bat
```

It seems OK to have the Yes.bat command output more Yes's than required by YourCommand.bat.  On Windows 7, they seem to be silently discarded...

The above only works with batch files, and, as you pointed out, does not address your question.

Your doskey macro can't be used in a batch file and, it seems, cannot be at the end of a pipe, so

```
Yes.bat | yourDOSKeyMacro
```

just fails.

For your question, I can't think of a generic answer, but the prompt is coming from the REG DELETE part of the macro.  You can get rid of this prompt with a /f (Force) option:

REG DELETE "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal  Server" /v "fDenyTSConnections" /f

I think that might get you most of the way there.

Comment: I'm really looking for a way to avoid doing this without a batch file. As I want it all just within the one .cmd file. Is there any way to echo or pipe ( < or > or | ) the yes into the Doskey?

More importantly your solution doesn't work. None of those strings ever actually go through the prompt.

Comment: I should have read the manual more thoroughly on reg /?. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

when i did this:

```
    C:\Windows\system32>echo y | del %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tt
```

i got this:

```
    C:\Users\qwerp\Desktop\tt\*, Are you sure (Y/N)? y

    C:\Windows\system32>
```

is this what you were looking for?

just echo the 'y' to your code like this:

echo y | [you code]